# Dockerfile how to stop aborting sudo prompt and install apps from bash script

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile, sudo

I have a Dockerfile that runs a bash script:

```
RUN curl -fsSL URL/remote-setup.sh | bash
```

`$URL/remote-setup.sh` snippet

```
curl -L $URL/tarball/master | tar -xzv -C $HOME/output_dir --strip-components=1
. "$HOME/output_dir/setup.sh"
```

`$HOME/output_dir/setup.sh` snippet

```
echo "Make sure we’re using the latest repositories"
    apt update

    echo " Upgrade any already-installed packages"
    apt upgrade

    apps=(
        awscli
        git
        golang-go
        mysql-server
        postgresql postgresql-contrib
        screenfetch
        tig
        tree
        zip
        zsh
    )
    echo "Installing..."
    apt install "${apps[@]}"
    unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
```

OUTPUT has error

```
#12 6.126 Installing...
#12 6.128
#12 6.128 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#12 6.128
#12 6.155 Reading package lists...
#12 6.699 Building dependency tree...
#12 6.829 Reading state information...
#12 6.965 The following additional packages will be installed:
...
#12 7.267 After this operation, 1498 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#12 7.267 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
#12 7.271   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#12 7.272                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 56.6M  100 56.6M    0     0  8848k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 13.2M
#12 13.83 ./dir/setup.sh: line 115: unzip: command not found
#12 13.84 sudo: ./sam-installation/install: command not found
```

The `unzip` command & other commands were not found because the list of apps were not installed. It needs to continue with `Y` rather than abort

Tried adding `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` but doesnt work
how do I fix it?  thanks

Comment: Read the logs: `#12 7.267 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.` So you have to use `-y` (answer **yes** to all questions)

Comment: (I'd recommend deleting the first block of Dockerfile code that sets up a nominally non-root user with unlimited `sudo` permissions and an easily-guessed hard-coded password; this doesn't improve security at all and you can just `docker run -u root` the container if you need to.  Also consider that the container only runs a single process, so installing multiple language runtimes and database servers and interactive shells will result in a very heavy-weight, mostly-unused image.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-y` at the end of your installation command... so that, apt continues installation without prompt... So, your final script should be something like below

```
echo "Make sure we’re using the latest repositories"
    apt update -y

    echo " Upgrade any already-installed packages"
    apt upgrade -y

    apps=(
        awscli
        git
        golang-go
        mysql-server
        postgresql postgresql-contrib
        screenfetch
        tig
        tree
        zip
        zsh
    )
    echo "Installing..."
    apt install "${apps[@]}" -y
    unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
```

Hope this helps...